# global.asax events not fired after publishing web application mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I recently converted a web forms application to an mvc4 application. I have still got all the aspx pages but with the mvc infrastructure.

I am facing a weird behavior though. When I publish the application in VS, then the global.asax is emitted as below:

```
<%@ Application Language="C#" %><script runat="server">

void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    // Code that runs on application startup

}

void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    //  Code that runs on application shutdown

}

void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    // Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs

}

void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    // Code that runs when a new session is started

}

void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    // Code that runs when a session ends. 
    // Note: The Session_End event is raised only when the sessionstate mode
    // is set to InProc in the Web.config file. If session mode is set to StateServer 
    // or SQLServer, the event is not raised.

}

void Application_BeginRequest(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Items["DbRepositoryFactory"] = new Bdequalizer.Model.DbRepositoryFactory();
}

void Application_EndRequest(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    var repositoryFactory = HttpContext.Current.Items["DbRepositoryFactory"] as Bdequalizer.Model.DbRepositoryFactory;

    if (repositoryFactory != null)
        repositoryFactory.Dispose();
}</script>
```

But the original global.asax is:-

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;
using Bdequalizer.Model;

namespace Web
{
// Note: For instructions on enabling IIS6 or IIS7 classic mode, 
// visit http://go.microsoft.com/?LinkId=9394801
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);


        RouteTable.Routes.RouteExistingFiles = false;
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);


    }

    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Items["DbRepositoryFactory"] = new Bdequalizer.Model.DbRepositoryFactory();
    }

    protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
        var repositoryFactory = HttpContext.Current.Items["DbRepositoryFactory"] as DbRepositoryFactory;

        if (repositoryFactory != null)
            repositoryFactory.Dispose();
    }
}
}
```

Now my problem is that Application_BeginRequest will not even fire. I have build action for global.asax as Content.

Let me know, if I am doing something wrong here.

Comment: C# code would get compiled to the assembly, I am not sure where the emitted global.asax get the methods. Could you check they are not strings in your global.asax (not global.asax.cs)?

Comment: No they are not strings.